# Issue mapping Array with knockout mapping

Tags: knockout.js

I have the following object returned from a HUB in SIGNALR and I want to map it to a object to use as a viewModel in knockout.

```
[{"Aprover":{"CurrentTask":null,"UserID":3,"MembershipKey":"admin","Name":"admin","StartCurrentTask":null,"TotalWorkSeconds":0},"Comments":[],"Creator":{"CurrentTask":null,"UserID":3,"MembershipKey":"admin","Name":"admin","StartCurrentTask":null,"TotalWorkSeconds":0},"ParentTask":null,"Project":null,"Steps":[{"StepDescription":"sdfsdfsdfsdf","StepID":1,"IsComplete":false,"IsValidated":false}],"TaskCategory":null,"UserAssigned":{"CurrentTask":null,"UserID":3,"MembershipKey":"admin","Name":"admin","StartCurrentTask":null,"TotalWorkSeconds":0},"ID":5,"Date":null,"Priority":0,"Title":"sdfsdf","Description":"","UnitTestName":null,"Status":0,"StepsText":"sdfsdfsdfsdf\n","StatusText":"Active"},{"Aprover":{"CurrentTask":null,"UserID":3,"MembershipKey":"admin","Name":"admin","StartCurrentTask":null,"TotalWorkSeconds":0},"Comments":[],"Creator":{"CurrentTask":null,"UserID":3,"MembershipKey":"admin","Name":"admin","StartCurrentTask":null,"TotalWorkSeconds":0},"ParentTask":null,"Project":null,"Steps":[{"StepDescription":"dfgdfg","StepID":2,"IsComplete":false,"IsValidated":false}],"TaskCategory":null,"UserAssigned":{"CurrentTask":null,"UserID":3,"MembershipKey":"admin","Name":"admin","StartCurrentTask":null,"TotalWorkSeconds":0},"ID":6,"Date":null,"Priority":0,"Title":"dfdd","Description":"","UnitTestName":null,"Status":0,"StepsText":"dfgdfg\n","StatusText":"Active"}]
```

I am using this to auto map:

```
Tasks = ko.mapping.fromJSON(res)
```

res = the object above;

the issue is Tasks is always a empty object no matter what I try, so I dont get a array.

**Extra note**

what if I want to add methods to the returned object? In other words I want to extend the array with custom methods like bellow

```
  var TaskListModel = function (data) {
        self = this;
        self.Items = ko.observableArray();
        if (data != null) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
        }

        self.selectedTask = ko.observable(null);
        self.selectedID = ko.observable(-1);

        self.selectTask = function (p) {
            if (self.selectedID() == p.ID())
                self.selectedID(-1); //Hide on click
            else
                self.selectedID(p.ID());
            self.selectedTask(p);
        }; //Create the select method
```

I tried to map to the items attribute but the problem persisted, I am all out of ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there's an issue with the newlines (`\n`) in the JSON.  I'm not sure if it's the mapping plugin or something else, but if you get rid of the `\n` in your JSON, the mapping plugin works fine.  I checked with:

```
var tasks = ko.mapping.fromJSON(res);
alert(tasks().length);
```

Remember that tasks will be an observableArray so you have to "execute" it to get the underlying array if you want to inspect it.

Here's a complete example using your JSON, but without the newlines:

http://jsfiddle.net/psteele/dKK55/

Comment: Odd, since I didnt change the server code and magically it stoped working.
Amazing answer thank you!